# When should you use subshells vs `xargs`?

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs, conventions, subshell

Many simple commands using `xargs` could be rewritten as commands using subshells. For instance, here is something I was using earlier today, to concatenate the ten largest binaries in `/usr/bin`, written using a subshell vs xargs:

subshell:

```
$ cat $(du -sh /usr/bin/* | sort -h | tail | cut -d "      " -f 2 | tr "\n" " ")
```

`xargs`:

```
$ du -sh /usr/bin/* | sort -h | tail | cut -d "      " -f 2 | tr "\n" " " | xargs cat
```

So when should you use a subshell and when should you use `xargs`?

### NOTE:

The delimiter for cut is a hard tab, which apparently doesn't display properly on SE.

Comment: For the sake of associations: Related is perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a slightly opinionated question but I'll just say this, it's highly dependent on 2 things:

1. What is the command you're going to run?
2. How many instances you're going to run?

If you're likely to run dozens to 100's of the same process, then `xargs` makes the most sense. Also if the processes are going to be expensive to start up, `xargs` is likely the best route to go.

If however there will only be a handful of instances of the command, then running them in a subshell is fine.

If the length of the arguments produced by the subshell will be extremely long, then you'd want to use `xargs`. But this limit is pretty extreme, typically 2MB-4MB of characters, so it's unlikely that you'd exceed it. You can check like this:

```
$ xargs --show-limits < /dev/null
Your environment variables take up 4805 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2090299
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2085494
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

By the way, neither of these commands appear to work. The `cut -d "      " -f2` is not valid, `cut` can only take a single character as the delimiter. Try this instead:

```
$ du -sh /usr/bin/* | sort -h | awk 'NR<=10 {print $2}' | tr "\n" " "
-or-
$ du -sh /usr/bin/* | sort -h | tail | cut -f2- | tr "\n" " "
```

Using `awk` here will likely cause you issues if you have any filenames or directories with spaces, so use it with caution.

```
$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 22 19:47 file 1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 22 19:47 file 2

$ du -sh * | sort -h | awk 'NR<=10 {print $2}' | tr "\n" " "
file file $
```

I'd use the `cut -f2-` method, but that's just me, others' might give you a more sophisticated `awk` solution, but use what makes the most sense to you.

#### Using awk + cat

**NOTE:** When piping output to `xargs` there is no need to call `cat`, `xargs` will automatically echo the output it's passed, by default.

```
$ du -sh * | sort -h | tail | cut -f2- | tr "\n" " " | xargs
file 1 file 10 file 2 file 3 file 4 file 5 file 6 file 7 file 8 file 9
```

#### EDIT #1

If you're using tabs to delimit with cut you don't need to do so explicitly, it defaults to that.

```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
```

Comment: The `cut` is valid (I used it earlier), it just seems to be that SE doesn't display hard tabs.

Comment: @haneefmubarak - it displays as 8 spaces.

Comment: *it just seems to be that SE likes to _soften_ hard tabs...

Comment: But the tab delimit is noted. Thanks for that.

Comment: @haneefmubarak - yeah I figured you tried them so it seemed odd. I've never tried pasting hard tabs, so you taught me something as well 8-).

Comment: So we both learned something, eh?

Comment: @haneefmubarak - it's often the case that the Q's push me to learn things I never knew, that's the main reason I try to answer the Q's 8-)

Comment: Ah, I see. I tend to do the same on SO [c] and CR.SE [c].